# Jsonpath - filter at child level to get parent attribute

Tags: jsonpath

Is there any way to extract "a" value by filtering on "d" in the following json?

```
[
  {
    "a":1,
    "b":{ "c":11,"d":12 }
  },

  {
    "a":2,
    "b":{ "c":21,"d":22}
  }
]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$..[?(@.b.d == 12)].a
```

above expression can solve this