# Need a json path expression for below json

Tags: json, expression, jsonpath

Need a JSON path expression for below JSON. I wanted to extract "Id" for each specific "name"

For Example: I need to extract "Id" : "3" for "name" : "XYZ" .

I tried a JSON path expression as $..Id which given output as:

```
[
   "1",
   "2",
   "3"
]
```

But I needed an Id specific to "name": "XYZ"`

```
[
   {
      "primary":{
         "name":"ABC"
      },
      "Id":"1"
   },
   {
      "primary":{
         "name":"PQR"
      },
      "Id":"2"
   },
   {
      "primary":{
         "name":"XYZ"
      },
      "Id":"3"
   }
]
```

Comment: Very similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/45173767/569662

Comment: Thank you .. I am able to solve this .. this can be solve by below expression .                             
                                                                                                                     
 $..[?(@.primary.name == 'XYZ')].Id

Answer (score 1):

Able to resolve this by below expression

```
$..[?(@.primary.name == 'XYZ')].Id
```

Comment: I wasn't able to make this work here https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: The link I was using does not use the Jayway implementation of jsonpath. I have asked them to support it