# json path expression to find a value corresponding to a particular name

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

need json path expression for below json.

To find appId corresponding to a name

```
[
  {
    "name": "a0vudemo",
    "appId": "80af20be-eddf-4b20-8d82"
  },
  {
    "name": "a1app",
    "appId": "55507d25-d025-4454-9443"
  },
  {
    "name": "a1appswan",
    "appId": "86cfa844-cf58-48b7-b56d"
  }
]
```

```
.name=="a1app"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need a json path expression for below json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207907/need-a-json-path-expression-for-below-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$..[?(@.name == 'a1app')].appId
```

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207907/need-a-json-path-expression-for-below-json)